# Does anyone have any tips javascipt in a new Rails 6 project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I was wondering what the 'correct' way to set up javascript is in a new Rails 6 project.

What are the correct commands involved in installing and using a library for example?

I'm currently using `bin/webpack-dev-server` to live reload js and react.

When adding a js package I'm adding it to the package.json in the root an running `yarn install`.

Then I'm including it with an ES6 include instead of like preview rails versions in the application.js file.

This is currently working but I'm not clear if I'm doing it the correct way, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the webpacker official documentation: https://github.com/rails/webpacker which was added to rails 6 to handle javascript, I personally have found more info about it that helped me to start with my project